# Problem with uploading and viewing images with django

Tags: python, django

Hope someone could help me, Thanks!
I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. I already read tons of articles about this problem but none of 'em have helped me. It's really simple, I'm trying to upload a dynamic image with django, but I keep having this problem.

The 'cover' attribute has no file associated with it.

```
    Environment:


    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/band/

    Django Version: 3.0.4
    Python Version: 3.8.2
    Installed Applications:
    ['search.apps.SearchConfig',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


    Template error:
    In template C:\Users\arian\Dev\db_vinili\src\dbvinili\search\templates\search\band.html, error at line 22
       The 'cover' attribute has no file associated with it.
       12 :     <div class="cat">
       13 :       <h2> BAND </h2>
       14 :     </div>
       15 : 
       16 : 
       17 : {% for Info in object_list %}
       18 :   <div class="container">
       19 : 
       20 :     <div class=album>
       21 :       <!-- insert an image -->
       22 :       <img src= " {{Info.cover.url}} " width="100%">
       23 : 
       24 :     </div>
       25 : 
       26 : 
       27 :     <div class="info">
       28 :       <!-- insert table info -->
       29 :       <table>
       30 :         <tr>
       31 :           <td> Band </td>
       32 :           <td> {{Info.band}}</td>


    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 828, in _resolve_lookup
        current = current[bit]

    During handling of the above exception ('ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
        response = response.render()
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
        self.content = self.rendered_content
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
        return template.render(context, self._request)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
        return self.template.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
        return self._render(context)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
        nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 986, in render
        output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 670, in resolve
        obj = self.var.resolve(context)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 795, in resolve
        value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 836, in _resolve_lookup
        current = getattr(current, bit)
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 61, in url
        self._require_file()
      File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 38, in _require_file
        raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

    Exception Type: ValueError at /band/
    Exception Value: The 'cover' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

View

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
    from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy

    from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

    from .models import Info, Search

    class bandView(ListView):
        model = Info
        template_name='search/band.html'
```

Comment: Can you provide us the view code?

Comment: Just edited the question with the view @FilipLavMaksimovic

Comment: @EdwardIVRadical can you include info model in question ? I guess `'cover' attribute has no file associated with it` means one of your info object cover field doesn't contain any image associated with it. However you can specify `default` parameter on `ImageField()`.

Comment: If one of your `Info` objects doesn't have a file, this will be the error. Wrap your `<img>` in an `{% if Info.cover %}` clause. Also you shouldn't call the for loop objects `Info`, call them `info` (no capital).

Comment: Yes it turned out that was the problem, not all object had an image. As @dirkgroten suggested I should have wrapped my <img> in an if

Comment: @dirkgroten in the for loop if I write Info without capital 'I' then it doesn't show nothing. What's the matter with capital and non-capital letters?

Comment: Everything is case-sensitive. So you also need to change it inside the loop `{{ info.cover.url }}`. In python names starting with a capital are classes. Variables should not have a capital.